# How to get the value of an attr jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've dynamically created multiples divs and I randomly assigned an attribute id ,called mine-data with a value of 10, to some of them, now I'm creating a function that looks for divs with attribute 'mine-data' and returns true. but it doesn't work. I've looked at similar questions and none of the answers worked.
Any idea how to make it work?

```
function isattr() {
    var attrb=$('.grid').attr('mine-data');    
    if(attrb==10) { 
       return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post html code.

Comment: What happens when you console log attrb?

Comment: I get undefined as a result.

Comment: Can you create a codepen?

Comment: Okay give me one second.

Comment: Here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JbymwR?editors=1011

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$('.grid')` will return object contains all of element with class `.grid`. If you want to create a `checking function`, you need to pass each of it. please review this one

```js
function isattr(elm) {
  var attrb = $(elm).attr('mine-data');
  //compare with string 10
  if (attrb === '10') {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

//get the array
var arrs = $('.grid').toArray();
//check for each element
arrs.forEach(function(elm) {
  // here we check each element and addEventListener      
  $(elm).on('click', function(e) {
     console.log(isattr(this));
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<div class="grid" mine-data=10>ok</div>
<div class="grid" mine-data=10>ok</div>
<div class="grid" mine-data=9>not</div>
<div class="grid">not</div>
<div class="grid" mine-data=10>ok</div>
```

Comment: This is a closer solution to what I'm looking. is there a way if I click on div with attr 10, it would console log true?

Comment: Yes of course. we can `addEventListener` to each `elm`. please check updated answer above and try to click each div.

Comment: glad it can help. regards

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`$.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/). Then supply a function inside which $(this) will be the concrete element.